# RemotingServices.Marshal() does not work when invoked from another AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I am trying to setup my object as remoting server. I use `RemotingServices.Marshal(myObj, uri)` for this. I have the following piece of code:

```
public class IpcRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Register()
    {
        var channel = new IpcChannel("ipcSample");
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        RemotingServices.Marshal(this, "test", typeof(IpcRemoteObject));
        Console.WriteLine("Created server, waiting for calls");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If I call this from Main() of my program like below, everything works:

```
// case 1: works
new IpcRemoteObject().Register();
```

However, if I create the object in another AppDomain like below, I get "RemotingException: Requested Service not found" when connecting from clients.

```
// case 2: completes without error, but client connections fail
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("foo");
var remoteObj = (IpcRemoteObject)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assembly, typename);
remoteObj.Register();
```

Then, if I create an intermediate class that makes call to Register() on my behalf and instantiate that class in another appdomain, everything is back to normal:

```
// case 3: works
class Bootstrapper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Register()
    {
         new IpcRemoteObject().Register();
    }
}
...
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("foo");
var bootstrapper = (Bootstrapper)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                                          bootstrapperAssembly, bootstrapperType);
bootstrapper.Register(); // works
```

So, here's the question: why `RemotingServices.Marshal()` does not work in case 2? Is there some kind of rule, or is it simply a bug in remoting? I am using .NET framework 4.5.